# Two level menu with jQuery

Tags: jquery, menu, frontend

I am currently working on two level menu. Here is my code - menu structure. When I hover on Parent 1, I want to show bottom `ul` with the same id. I made the jquery code but i have problem with `mouseleave`.

HTML Structure

```
<section id="top-nav">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li data-href="menu-id-1">
                <a href="">Parent 1</a>
            </li>

            <li data-href="menu-id-2">
                <a href="">Parent 2</a>
            </li>

            <li data-href="menu-id-0">
                <a href="">Parent 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>

<section id="bottom-nav">
     <nav>
        <ul class="child-ul" id="menu-id-1">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Parent 1 Children li</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">Parent 1 Children li</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">Parent 1 Children li</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">Parent 1 Children li</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">Parent 1 Children li</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="child-ul" id="menu-id-2">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Parent 2 Children li</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">Parent 2 Children li</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">Parent 2 Children li</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">Parent 2 Children li</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">Parent 2 Children li</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">Parent 2 Children li</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>
```

jQuery (code is a mess, but I tried different ways)

```
 $(function () {
     $("#top-nav ul li").mouseover(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         data = $(this).attr("data-href");
         $("#" + data).css("display", "block").addClass('ul-active');
         $(this).children().addClass("active");
         active = true;

     }).mouseleave(function () {
         liactive = this;

         $(".ul-active").mouseleave(function () {
             $("#" + data).css("display", "none").removeClass('ul-active');
             $(liactive).children().removeClass("active");
         });
         $("#bottom-nav").not().mouseleave(function () {
             $("#" + data).css("display", "none").removeClass('ul-active');
             $(liactive).children().removeClass("active");
         });
         if ($(liactive).attr("data-href") == 'menu-id-0') {
             $(liactive).children().removeClass("active");
         }
     });
 });
```

I know this is very simple, but I can not find the right way and I'm kinda tired, so I guess I do not think properly.

Comment: You are connecting event handlers inside event handlers. That is always a problem you need to avoid/fix first.

Comment: Can you point this places in my code please?

Comment: `$(".ul-active").mouseleave` and other handlers inside `$("#top-nav ul li").mouseleave` handler.

Comment: Right, no i see it. Thank you. Can you show me the way how should it work?

Comment: `.not()` without arguments returns full list of previously selected elements (which in your case probably consists of one element due to selecting by ID). What was this written for? About "handlers in handlers" - handlers should be moved out from another handler, but I can't think normally now, so I can't say how not to loose `liactive = this;` inside handlers. Maybe RNKushwaha's answer is correct, maybe someone else will answer, maybe I will do tomorrow...

Comment: It would help if you describe the desired behavior. The code may need a complete re-write, so good to know the aim :)

Comment: The problem is with hovering second ul, how to keep it display. The second issue is the moment when you switch from one parent li to another to not show two li elements a the same time.

Comment: @Badworker this is how I understood what you want: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qt17npne/1/).

Comment: @Regent Thank you! It works exactly as I want. You saved my life. I really need to learn JavaScript better, cause now i need to waste a lot of time to do something in this language. Do you know how can i mark your answer as correct for others?

Comment: @Badworker you're welcome. As fiddle appears to be correct, I'll post its code as answer in a few minutes, so that you can accept it.

Comment: @Regent Yes it works. I just copied and pasted it into my document.

Comment: @Badworker but it's also important to understand how it works :) So if my short description of answer is not sufficient, you can say what I should clarify in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide previously shown second menu in main menu's `mouseover` handler.
And to hide current shown second menu you can use `$(document).on("mouseleave", ".ul-active"`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qt17npne/1/).

```
$(function()
{
    $("#top-nav ul li").mouseover(function()
    {
        hideSecondMenu();
        var data = $(this).attr("data-href");
        $("#" + data).addClass('ul-active');
        $(this).children().addClass("active");
        return false;
    });

    $(document).on("mouseleave", ".ul-active", function()
    {
        hideSecondMenu();
    });

    function hideSecondMenu()
    {
        $(".ul-active").removeClass('ul-active');
        $("#top-nav ul li .active").removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
#top-nav ul li
{
    display: inline
}

.child-ul
{
    display: none;
}

.active
{
    color: red;
}

.ul-active
{
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like this. I thnk there is no need to use mouseleave separetely, you can pass a function in hover() like below code. Hover(function(e), function(e)). here first will be for hover and second will be for mouseleave.

```
$(".yourselectorbyclass").hover(function(e) {
  var timeout = $(this).data("timeout");
  e.stopPropagation();

  if(timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);

  $(".yourselectortoshow").show();

 //your code here

}, function() {
    $(this).data("timeout", setTimeout($.proxy(function(e) {
    $(".yourselectortoshow").hide();
    //your code here
    }, this), 100));
});
```

Comment: It works but not exactly. It shows second ul, but when you 'mousleave' from parent li to pick some options from second ul it disappeared.